# Resize table headers/row to match the first row in the table when the table changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to figure out how to get the widths of my table/column headers to match the table rows. The table rows width changes depending on the table that is selected. Cant get a function to resize the table header according to the rows to work.

I would like for the second th widths to match the widths of the table rows when the data is brought in. I have tried a lot of different things but cant seem to make it work. Trying to use a function that will get the first row and resize the table header. I think I am just missing something fairly small but I dont know for sure. Its becoming annoying at this point. I would appreciate any help on this thank you.

Heres the php

```
$result = @mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<div>
<table class='scroll' id='table'>
<thead>
<tr>
        <th class=\"th1\"colspan=\"6\">Huntsville Hospital(Main) Carousel 
Report
        <input type='text' id='myInput' onkeyup='searchfunction()' 
align='right' placeholder='Search...'> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>MedID</th>
    <th>Medication Description</th>
    <th>Current Count</th>
    <th>Current Min</th>
    <th>Current Max</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";
 if($resultCheck > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    "<tbody>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td class='mednum'>" . $row['MedID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row ['MedDescription']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='countnum'>" . $row ['CurrentCount']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='countnum'>" . $row ['Currentmin']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='countnum'>" . $row ['CurrentMax']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='locationcol'>" . $row ['Location']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    "</tbody>";
}
echo "</table>
    </div>";
}
```

Here is the js

```
var $table = $('table.scroll'),
$bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').resultCheck(),
colWidth;

// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
// Get the tbody columns width array
colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();

// Set the width of thead columns
$table.find('thead tr').resultCheck().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
});    
}).resize();
```

Here is my css

```
table{

border: 1px solid black;
border: collapse;
position: relative;


}

td, tr {

border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;

}
table.scroll {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll tbody {
height: 525px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead { display: block; }

td.countnum {

width: 9%;
text-align: right;
}
td.mednum{
width: 15%;
text-align: right;
}
td.locationcol{
width: 5%;
}
thead {
text-align: center;
color:black;
}
th{
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
background-color: lightgreen;
color: black;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
background: white;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even){
background: lightgray
}

#myInput{
    background: white url(searchicon.png) right no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-size: 20%;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 5px;      
    border: 1px solid green;

}
.th1{
background-color: lightgreen;
text-align: center;
color:black;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: If you know how to add jquery plugins to your table you can just add datatables and it will do that for you with ease. I see you are using jquery

Comment: I can get it to resize until I put the rows below the header into a tbody with a scroll function then it all goes to hell.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand your problem correctly, but i see a few issues:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    "<tbody>"; // <- no echo and inside while loop
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td class='mednum'>" . $row['MedID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row ['MedDescription']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='countnum'>" . $row ['CurrentCount']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='countnum'>" . $row ['Currentmin']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='countnum'>" . $row ['CurrentMax']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='locationcol'>" . $row ['Location']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    "</tbody>"; // <- no echo and inside while loop
}
```

This is probably not a "real" issue, since most browsers add the missing `tbody` tags by themselves and which would make your `tbody tr:first` query work, but still i would fix it.

Also it is not clear what `.resultCheck()` does - but i assume it does some kind of validation or so and returns the originally matched jQuery selector result.

The next problem i see is:

```
colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();

$table.find('thead tr').resultCheck().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
});
```

You do this on window resize and directly trigger a window resize - so the width will never change since the first call because the `td`'s below naturally inherit the `th`'s width.

In general it is not very clear for me what you want to achieve with this - if you omit the width-setting altogether it will probably behave the way you want it to. Check the following example:

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
const data = {
  'one': [
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6']
  ],
  'two': [
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
    ['Col1 with a long text', 'Col2', 'Col 3 text', 'Col 4 text', 'Col 5 number', 'Col 6'],
  ]
};
const loadData = function(id) {
  while(tbody.firstChild) tbody.firstChild.remove();
  for(let row of data[id]) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(let cell of row) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerText = cell;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
}

document.querySelector('#one').addEventListener('click', () => loadData('one'));
document.querySelector('#two').addEventListener('click', () => loadData('two'));
document.querySelector('#fixSize').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let headers = document.querySelectorAll('thead tr:last-child th');
  let firstRow = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:first-child td');
  for(let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].style.width = firstRow[i].clientWidth + 'px';
  }
});
document.querySelector('#freeSize').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let headers = document.querySelectorAll('thead tr:last-child th');
  for(let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].style.width = null;
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
th, td {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr>
<button id="one">Load one</button>
<button id="two">Load two</button>
<hr>
<button id="fixSize">Fix size</button>
<button id="freeSize">Free size</button>
```